# Adding Hover Over Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, delay, popover

I have tried setTimeout but seems not to be working with bootstrap popover. I have tried wrapping the "$(this).popover("show");" in a timeout which is triggered if certain class is on the element but seems not to work.

The popover is manual as this allows me to hover of the product as well as the popover itself without it disappearing.

Goal: Be able to hover over product for 500ms without popover displaying.

Any help appreciated.

```
$(".pop").each(function () {
      var $pElem = $(this);
      $pElem.popover(
          {
              html: true,
              trigger: "manual",
              title: getPopoverTitle($pElem.attr("id")),
              content: getPopoverContent($pElem.attr("id")),
              container: 'body',
              animation: false,
              placement: function (context, source) {
                  var position = $(source).position();
                  if (position.left > 615) {
                      return "left";
                  }
                  if (position.left < 615) {
                      return "right";
                  }
              }
          }
      );
  }).on("mouseenter", function () {
      var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
        $(".popover").on("click", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");

            }
        }, 100);
    });

    function getPopoverTitle(target) {
        return $("#" + target + "_content > h3.popover-title").html();
    };

    function getPopoverContent(target) {
        return $("#" + target + "_content > div.popover-content").html();
    };
```

HTML

```
   <div class="product-div pop mll mbl pull-left "  id="@item.Id" >@Html.Partial("_ProductBookBox", item)</div>
 /**PRODUCT PARTIAL***/<div class="container-product">
            <div class="product-small" style='background-image: url(@Model.ImageURL);'>
                <div class="product-overlay">
                    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Product", new { SeName = Model.SeName })" class="product-button info"></a>

                </div>
                <div class="product-content">
                    <div class="product-add-content">
                        <div class="product-add-content-inner">
                            <div class="section">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary buy expand">Buy now</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you add some HTML?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/sTny3/

Comment: Still can't get it right. Got it somewhat working when adding setTimeout to show when $(.pop:hover).lenght is true but then hovering over the other .pops counts towards the timeout and then displays multiple popovers